# How to reuse same method from other component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

How can I refactor two components which needs to use exactly the same methods? defining a parent component and the same method there?

```
Vue.component("one", {
  method: {
    functionA:
  }
});

Vue.component("two", {
  method: {
    functionA
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can always create a [mixin](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html):

```js
var mixin = {
  methods: {
    consoleMessage() {
      console.log('hello from mixin!')
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.consoleMessage()
  }
}

Vue.component('one', {
  mixins: [mixin],
  template: `<div>one</div>`
})

Vue.component('two', {
  mixins: [mixin],
  template: `<div>two</div>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <one></one>
  <two></two>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

No disagreement that a mixin could be used here, but this also can be solved with plain javascript.

```js
function consoleMessage(){
  console.log("hello from regular old javascript!")
}

Vue.component('one', {
  template: `<div>one</div>`,
  methods: { consoleMessage },
  created() { this.consoleMessage() }
})

Vue.component('two', {
  template: `<div>two</div>`,
  methods: { consoleMessage },
  created() { this.consoleMessage() }
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<div id="app">
  <one></one>
  <two></two>
</div>
```

If you use modern modules, you can define the function you want to share in a module and import it into both components.

**shared.js**

```
export function consoleMessage(){
  console.log("hello from regular javascript!")
}
```

**componentOne.js**

```
import { consoleMessage } from "./shared"

export default {
  template: `<div>one</div>`,
  methods: { consoleMessage },
  created() { this.consoleMessage() }
}
```

**componentTwo.js**

```
import { consoleMessage } from "./shared"

export default {
  template: `<div>two</div>`,
  methods: { consoleMessage },
  created() { this.consoleMessage() }
}
```